# PHP exercise cheapest flight

Tags: php

So i want to find the cheapest flight with as many as stopover necessary in a PHP function.

```
$flights = [
["departure" => "BRI", "arrival" => "BDS", "price" => 20],
["departure" => "BRI", "arrival" => "ANC", "price" => 5],
["departure" => "ANC", "arrival" => "CRV", "price" => 3],
["departure" => "CRV", "arrival" => "BDS", "price" => 4],
["departure" => "CRV", "arrival" => "BRI", "price" => 2],
["departure" => "CRV", "arrival" => "XLR", "price" => 3],
["departure" => "SUF", "arrival" => "BDS", "price" => 5],
["departure" => "FLR", "arrival" => "NAP", "price" => 10],
["departure" => "FLR", "arrival" => "BDS", "price" => 1],
["departure" => "FLR", "arrival" => "FRA", "price" => 5],
["departure" => "NAP", "arrival" => "CRV", "price" => 12],
["departure" => "NAP", "arrival" => "BDS", "price" => 16],
["departure" => "NAP", "arrival" => "FLR", "price" => 1],
["departure" => "XLR", "arrival" => "BRI", "price" => 3],
["departure" => "BOL", "arrival" => "FRA", "price" => 3],
["departure" => "BOL", "arrival" => "FLR", "price" => 10],
["departure" => "FRA", "arrival" => "NAP", "price" => 3],
```

Assuming this table the function with "BRI" --> "BDS" should give me "12" (BRI->ANC, ANC->CRV CRV->BDS)

```
function giveMeLower($departure, $arrival) { global $flights; $price = 0;

foreach ($flights as $flight) {
    if (($flight["departure"] == $departure) and ($flight["arrival"] == $arrival)) {
        $price = $flight["price"];
    }
}

foreach ($flights as $volo) {
    if (($volo["departure"] == $departure)) {

        $tempPrice = $volo["price"];
        $scalo = $volo["arrival"];

        foreach ($flights as $volo_int) {
            if (($volo_int["departure"] == $scalo) and $volo_int["arrival"] == $arrival) {
                $tempPrice += $volo_int["price"];
                if ($tempPrice < $price || $price == 0) {
                    $price = $tempPrice;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return $price == 0 ? "No flight found" : $price;
}
```

This is what i tried, it works but only with one stopover.

Some suggestion to make it go as long as it can?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code only checks for a single stopover point. You first check for a direct connection, then you look for one matching departure, take the destination, loop through and check for the second arrival matching your destination, and if the price works, it exits. That said, your code returns "20" for me, but I suspect it would return a different price if you had a connection between "ANC" and "BDS". Your recursion will need to check for a loop, and for the possibility of there being no alternate route, of course. Or no route at all.

Comment: I started having a play with this but unfortunately I've run out of time for now. It is more complicated than it looks. I started by building an array of start-points that match your departure, with the intention of running through each one, then following the route to the destination. But, you also need to run through each possible route, so for every leg on the journey you also need to consider not just the selection of starting points, but also the selection of options for each and every step.

Comment: It'll be interesting to see what others suggest for this, now I think about it further. If you sit down and write out all the possible options by hand, does that give you any clues as to the best way to code it?

Comment: I was thinking about something recursive, like keep checking if current flight["arrival"]  is present on the departure table and keep checking until current flight["arrival"] is equal to $arrival but i can't make it work

Comment: It's an interesting exercise, for sure.

Comment: If you want the most optimized way to do it, you could take a look at the Bellman Ford algorythm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm

Answer (score 3):

[Yuya Aratani](https://github.com/taniko/dijkstra), did a great job on this I think. Adapt from  Dijkstra's algorithm.

The "Graph" class is simple and efficient. And it does exactly the job you want!

```
require 'src/Graph.php';

$graph = Taniko\Dijkstra\Graph::create();

$graph
    ->add('BRI', 'BDS', 20)
    ->add('BRI', 'ANC', 5)
    ->add('ANC', 'CRV', 3)
    ->add('CRV', 'BDS', 4)
    ->add('CRV', 'BRI', 2, false)
    ->add('CRV', 'XLR', 3)
    ->add('SUF', 'BDS', 5)
    ->add('FLR', 'NAP', 10)
    ->add('FLR', 'BDS', 1)
    ->add('FLR', 'FRA', 5)
    ->add('NAP', 'CRV', 12)
    ->add('NAP', 'BDS', 16)
    ->add('NAP', 'FLR', 1)
    ->add('XLR', 'BRI', 3, false)
    ->add('BOL', 'FRA', 3)
    ->add('BOL', 'FLR', 10)
    ->add('FRA', 'NAP', 3);

$route = $graph->search('BRI', 'BDS');
$cost  = $graph->cost($route);
```

Returns

```
var_dump($route);//array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "BRI" [1]=> string(3) "ANC" [2]=> string(3) "CRV" [3]=> string(3) "BDS" }
echo $cost;//12
```